# Finding example of a particular group

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification, sylow-theory, dihedral-groups

Give an example of a group $G$ of order $p^2q$ where $p$ and $q$ are distinct prime numbers satisfying $q\not\equiv 1 \pmod{p}$ which does not have a unique $q$-Sylow subgroup.

My attempt:

Consider the dihedral group of 9-gon $D_9$. Then $O(D_9)=18=3^2×2$. Clearly $2 \not\equiv 1 \pmod{3}$. There are 9 axes of symmetry for 9-gon. So reflection about each axis gives a 2-Sylow subgroup. So we get at least 9 2-Sylow subgroups.

Will tHis example work?

Comment: Seems fine to me! (In fact you you get exactly those $9$ Sylow $2$-groups).

Comment: $S_3\times C_3$ has order $9\cdot 2=3^2\cdot 2$ and $3$ Sylow $2$-subgroups, $2\not\equiv 1\pmod{3}$.

Comment: My guess is that the condition should have been $p \not\equiv 1 \bmod q$. That prevents you using nonabelian groups of order $pq$.